# Voltage reference using zener diode and transistor

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, diodes

Below is a circuit presented in a book as a stable voltage reference circuit. [image]

The other says that "**Vref=Vz+0.6**". I am not convainced about this equation, and I think that **Vref is just VZ** because of the virtual ground of the OPAMP. If I am not right, that means there is a trick in that circuit.

Please can anyone confirme to me the formula given by the other and how he did that ??

Comment: I agree with you, I think Vref=Vz and the output voltage of the op amp is Vz+0.6V.

Comment: I  do not agree. @ElliotAlderson... Vout=0 unless Vin+ is around 10  mV above Vin- and since Vin-. must be >0 by design , it will not work, but with the right bias to 20~50mV it will work as Vout=Vz at chosen current

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 - if you look at the schematic in my answer you will see that the +input is disabled so the amplifier acts as a simple non-differential single-stage CE amplifier. It should work as stated but does not compensate for the Vbe change with temperature.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson - actually the output of the opamp will be Vz + 1.2V. There is the Vbe of Q1 as well as the Vbe of the input stage of the amplifier.

Comment: @KevinWhite Thanks for clarifying, I did not realize that the MC3401 had the unusual input state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the designer (grad student) was having a bad day....

MC3401 has NPN inputs unlike the quad LM324 with PNP inputs that operate to Vee =0V.

The **3401 must have Vin+>Vin-** by having a slight +ve input offset current.

Otherwise if Vin->Vin+ the output goes low and stays there no matter how much negative feedback.

When this condition occurs. the Zener current, Iz causes Iz*R1 = __ mV for the stable low Zener current then near null offset and Vout=Vz @ Iz

Since Vin+ has lower input bias current than the collector Vin- then Vin+ will have a lower input voltage than Vin- which forces the output at 0V.

So Vin+ must never be 0V=Gnd. It must be slightly > Vin- otherwise the Norton or any Op Amp will not work.  This takes 3 R's/ Pull up/down and series R.

Comment: So under these conditions (as it is designed) will never work and Vout is always 0V !

Comment: If you look at the schematic in my answer you'll see that it can work if the Vin+ is grounded but it is not differential anymore just a simple single stage amplifier.

Comment: understood but.. still non -functional http://tinyurl.com/v8ojx5v @KevinWhite

Comment: yet with Rbias adding input R makes it work.  http://tinyurl.com/ugghkyz

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 - I'm not sure what you are attempting to show with the triangle generator at the input. R1 needs to go to ground to set the zener current.

Comment: @KevinWhite  The triangle simulates a range of bias to see effects.  It only works when resistors are inserted as shown.  http://tinyurl.com/wqgb6ha

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 - the voltage from your triangle generator is much too large, you only need about +/-25mV to swing the amplifier over most of its full output range. It looks like you have 500mV.

Comment: That is just a design test for hysteresis. R1 to gnd fails to work unless a large series R is inserted on input. Of Norton Amp and generator is removed on last link.  Try changing R input to 0  or in between

Answer (score 1):

The antiquated MC3401 is not a normal opamp. It is actually of a type called a Norton amplifier and cannot be replaced by any modern types.

I would not recommend using this circuit even though the equation is correct.

There are many better solutions available now.

Here is an image of one section of the internal circuitry from [RadioMuseum.Org](https://www.radiomuseum.org/tubes/tube_mc3401.html).

It has a single common emitter amplifier stage with an output buffer.

The additional transistor Q3 and diode CR1 means that it responds to the difference between the input CURRENTs rather than the input VOLTAGES as any current injected in Vin(-) will be counteracted by the current from the current mirror Q3/CR1.

[image]

Comment: I was going to say "which museum did they pull out this voltage regulator? Just a few years  before BandGap diodes came out AFAIK, which is why I never used them.